# Printer Epson LX300+ Always print full A4 paper ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, printing

i want to ask, i have report HTML, and i have set paper size in my report.
I am using continuous form (9,5inch x 11/2 inch) so basically 9,5 x 5,5.
But when i print with Epson LX300+ it is always print full page 9.5 x 11 not 9.5 x 5.5

how to set up my print so i can print just half page?
thank you

Comment: Use the CUPS admin interface at http://localhost:631

Comment: I did, but it didnt work

Comment: "didn't work" gives NO information on what you did and why you think it didn't work.

Comment: Use the CUPS admin interface to add a new printer, using the SAME URI, same driver, but different paper settings. Read `man lpoptions enable disable` to learn how to tell applications about paper size, and how to switch the active printer.